# Formatting error in list of tables with alternative naming

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

When using an alternative prefix - namely a long one - for table indices, I receive an erroneous output in the list of tables.

Minimal (non-) working example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{TAppendix\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\chapter{Chapter Title}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 Hello & world! \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption[TOC Title]{This is the full caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This code leads to this entry in the list of tables:

[image: Erroneous LOT-entry]

while the caption on the table itself is fine:

[image: Table with caption]

**How do I adapt the formatting in the list of tables so that there is no overlap between table index and short title?**

The hacky way of adding spaces did not really work and I would like to avoid adding white filler letters just for the optics (as I also need to publish digital copies online).

I receive this error during compiling with `pdflatex`, which I assume to be relevant, but cannot interpret:

```
(./toctest.lot
Overfull \hbox (38.66676pt too wide) detected at line 2
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 TAppendix1.1 
) [2]
```